# Writing functions to binary files?

Tags: c++, function, file, io, binary

Something that made me fairly curious was that since it's possible in C++ to pass a function as an argument under the right circumstances, that would suggest that whatever internal code handles that function can be pointed to and otherwise written and read into a binary as its executable code.

This is obviously coming from someone while I may have a strong background in C++, I'm not familiar with the intricate internals in just how memory is managed in the heap and especially how the executable machine code fits into the picture.

I assume since it's possible to pass around the reference to a function, it's possible to get the data pointed to by it and write it somewhere. I don't know.

Anyone want to tell me if this is possible? If so, can you give an example? If not, please tell me why! I love learning more in-depth about how C++ actually works internally.

Comment: I cannot give you an example but however you can imagine that the function pointers just say: hey here is a executable code which you can invoke.

Comment: Considering what executables are... ;P

Comment: @rekire See, that was my thought process too. Obviously the executable code has to be present somewhere in memory to be ran, but I've never actually tried getting it and writing it to a file.

The idea came when I was thinking of really weird, out-of-the-box solutions to literally saving functions in files and then having my program be able to load and execute them. Lol.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure the practical applications of something like this, but it's a really interesting thought experiment that I thought would be really cool to try.

Comment: What you wrote in the first comment soulds like a shared library like a .dll file in windows or .so files in linux/unix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

20 years ago your suggestions could be fresh and usable. People were saving memory by loading code from file on demand , then calling it, then unloading. That was called overlays. To certain level it IS usable, but in form that is standardized in platform and platform's API is what manages it. 
Mechanism behind shared libraries (.so in POSIX system, .dll in  Windows) is that library's file contains labels where certain functions are , what their name is, as well as data about how stack and data segment should be initialized. It can be done by system automatically, when program is loaded. Otherwise you can load library manually and load pointer to function. E.g. on Windows that would be by LoadLibrary() and GetProcAddress(),  dlopen() and dlsym() on Linux.

Reason why it isn't possible now in high level language: security, protection from malicious code in data segment. Run-time library usually handles it.
It is still possible using assembler, but you will challenge antivirus and system security measures. With careful programming you may create own "linker" be able to create your own library and load , I suppose.

Comment: It is still possible to do this on many targets - the kind of targets you are referring to from 20 years ago are still in wide use in embedded systems, and not necessarily legacy or antique.  There are are great many modern microcontrollers without an MMU/MPU (Most ARM Cortex-M devices for example).  Also the question is about *reading* the code only, it says nothing about subsequently loading and executing it.

Answer (score 1):

No,  you can't really do this.   There are a whole lot of reasons, but here's a simple and intuitive one: functions may call other functions.  If you were able to write a function to disk, and restore it, this would not account for its dependencies (functions it calls, global variables it updates, etc.).  It won't work.

If you want to read functions from disk, it is better to express them in a scripting language like Lua.  This is a proven solution which is used in many commercial products such as video games and Adobe Lightroom.

Comment: I'm curious to see what information you actually get from a function by saving it, though. If it loses any dependencies, then what will I see when I pull it from memory? Obviously a scripting language is much better for these purposes, but I just thought it was a fun question to ask.

Comment: I imagine execute disable and address relocation would be a problem as well.

Comment: @Kats : If you want to see what the memory of a function's code looks like use a debugger in *disassembly* mode.  That will make a great deal more sense than a raw binary copy - you will see all the links and dependencies.  Note that this answer is not exactly correct; you can do it; it is just not very useful.

Comment: @GRAYgoose124 I guess that's true. Any function calls or memory management that might be made inside of the "loaded" function would be completely invalidated by the fact that the references to each of them aren't going to be pointing to what it thinks it should.

I'd foresee nothing but a lot of segmentation faults coming out of that. Lol.

Comment: Not to mention Kats, how to do find the function bounds to know when to stop copying? :)

Comment: @GRAYgoose124 in fact, I doubt that modern compiler will allow you to see function code. Pointers to functions might be implemented differently, through call table, exports, whatever. It's not  standardized by  language standard

Comment: The question asks only how the binary may be written to a file; it does not suggest any purpose of subsequent usage (such as reloading and running it elsewhere).  In that sense it is entirely possible - function bounds notwithstanding.  Is just that it serves no useful purpose (at least not one better and more easily solved by other means).

Comment: @Clifford : only with runtime checks off and not on all platforms. For that to be possible, code segment must be read, but there might be protection against that. Oh, and some systems require superuser rights for that. Certainly it is possible in assembler, I once wrote software that was compressing PEXE file on windows, infecting it with decompressor that would uncompress it before running. Does it sound to you like a virus?

Comment: @Swift : Of course, there are many caveats; this answer though is rather emphatic, and makes assumptions about some higher purpose to the question (there is none apparently), in order to essentially answer an unasked question.

Comment: @Clifford: The question says "written and read" and also says "get the data pointed to by it" (I took this to mean global variables).  The question wasn't written quite so narrowly.

Comment: @JohnZwinck :  True, but reading a file does not imply *execution*.  It would be a pretty pointless file if it were write-only.  The part about the "data pointed to by it" I missed, but the same problem occurs with any external (to the function) link such as function calls which I did cover.  In the end it is really an XY problem; it seems he wants to learn about how the compiler/linker/loader organises code and data in memory and the best way to do that is with a debugger rather then modifying the code to essentially inspect itself.

Answer (score 0):

While a function pointer is the entry point of a function, and that memory can be read and therefore copied, the first problem is that there is no reliable means of determining the length of that code, so you cannot determine for certain *how much* to copy to get the entire function and only that.

The other issue is to what practical end? Depending on the platform the code may not be relocatable and will have links to other code.  The binary contains no symbolic information; the best you can do is disassemble it, but out of the context of the entire linked executable it may not be very useful to do so.

If your aim is to separate functions from the primary executable, and to be able to later load and run them, then that is what DLLs and shared libraries are for.

If you just want to observe the binary relating to a function, then that is best done in a debugger - it will have a disassembly view mode that will show the raw binary (in hexadecimal), assembly code with symbolic links and the corresponding C source.  This makes a lot more sense if your aim is merely to investigate how source code relates to binary machine code.

Below is how you could possibly do what you are asking - even if there is no practical reason for doing it.  It makes assumptions about the behaviour of the compiler that may not be valid in some cases.  It assumes for example that the compiler will place adjacent functions contiguously in memory and in increasing memory address, so that `function2` is immediately *after* `function1` in memory.  Here `function2` serves only as an end marker for `function1` and may be dummy.

```
int function1()
{
    ...

    return 0 ;
}

void function2() 
{
}

#include <stddef.h>

int main()
{
    ptrdiff_t function1_length = (char*)function2 - (char*)function1 ;

    FILE* fp = fopen( "function1.bin", "wb" ) ;
    fwrite( function1, function1_length, 1, fp ) ;
    fclose( fp ) ;
}
```

Comment: I never said anything about being practical or having a use. I just had a question about whether something like this was feasible. More can be gained from playing with ideas than just "progress". With that being said, I did exactly that, pulled the address of the function and ran into the exact problem you described: there's no method to accurately determine how long the buffer should be. Regardless of any pragmatic use, it's not wasted effort. I learned a bit more about how memory works at runtime, which is really interesting.

Comment: @Kats : I appreciate that; but it was not clear that the question was not an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), and that you did not have some unstated aim in mind.  As a community resource, it is useful to an answer to include such health warnings, in case some other reader thinks it might be a solution to a problem you never intended.

Comment: Sorry about that. Yeah, it was more of a learning experience rather than finding some practical use for it. If there were one, I would have probably found it with a quick google search, but since not many programmers seem to worry about writing functions to files, it's probably not something worth investing a lot of time into. Unless you're a library writer, then it's pretty much your job. Lol.

Comment: In this answer you write *something* but it is not clear *what*.  What if the thing at `&function1` is simply a jump instruction to somewhere else?  You haven't captured `function1`, but merely that part of it which lies before `function2`.

Comment: @Kats : Note that everything you *learned* would have been more easily studied within a symbolic debugger or disassembler.  The advantage being that you do not have to modify the code you are studying in order to study it.

Comment: @JohnZwinck That would explain a lot about why the buffer is zero in his calculation. Lol.

Comment: there might be some padding between functions anyway, but that is  safe on x86 Linux and on Windows. Not sure if x64 Linux, I assume, pointer there is a structure. I have non-x86 (a weird 128-bit SPARC) target  platform at work where it wont work.  Well, it will work but instead it would just write several words from function table, the REAL address of function is stored in memory where pointer points)

Comment: @JohnZwinck : As I stated (possibly after or while you posted the comment) it makes a number of assumptions about the compiler.  In my experience however, it is very likely to work.  As a systems-level language C translation is generally very direct in order to ensure performance.  It would be an unusual compiler that would add a level of indirection to a function call, however it is possible that compiler optimisation would break this approach.

Comment: @Kats : Zero length is liklly due either to the empty function or the fact that the function is not called and is therefore optimised to no-code.  It was intended to be illustrative of the technique; you have to apply the approach to *real* code to get a useful result.

Comment: @Kats actually, a lot of programmers do that. They write compilers (or linkers\OS kernel at least)

Comment: @Swift : There may be padding - very likely in a debug build.  The aim here is not to truncate the function and have *at least* the entirety of the function, rather then *exactly* the body of the function.  I have clearly stated that it makes a number of assumptions that may not hold in all cases.

Comment: callable objects usually have to be aligned by word.16 bytes in my case. Btw, what to do if <stddef> doesn't exist? I can't test this in retexter

Comment: @Swift : Intended <stddef.h>;  `ptrdiff_t` is an alias for some sort of integer ; in this case a plain `int` would probably suffice, but likely involve an implicit cast.  The code contains no checks; it might be wise to check that the diff is not negative, otherwise it will write a very large file when cast to `size_t`.  If it *is* negative of course the implicit  assumptions are invalid.  What is retexter?

Comment: I am somewhat intrigued that directly answering the question asked gets a downvote while answering a different question than that asked should get upvotes.  Since the question appears to be about experimental code, I see no reason why the answer should be universally applicable - it is an experiment.